# how to pass a pointer to a pointer to a struct member?

Tags: c

So the problem at hand is to convert a string of digits in the format YYYYMMDD to
a struct tm type member within some other structure. Truth is, I really only care
about getting a struct tm with reasonable values in it.

Consider the following struct :

```
typedef struct some_node {
    char somestring[64];
    char anotherstring[128];
    struct tm date_one;
    struct tm date_two;
    int some_val;
    struct some_node *prev;
    struct some_node *next;
} some_node_t;
```

Inside there I have two members of type struct tm from the time.h header. Seems
very reasonable. Also there are pointer members in there to make a linked list
however that isn't the issue.

So I create the first node in my yet to be created linked list like so :

```
/* begin the linked list of some_node_t */
struct some_node *t_head =
                calloc( (size_t) 1, sizeof( some_node_t ) );
if ( t_head == NULL ) {
    /*Memory allocation fault */
    printf ( " FAIL : Memory allocation fault at %s(%d)\n",
               __FILE__, __LINE__  );
    exit ( EXIT_FAILURE );
}

/* I used calloc above which zero fills memory so these 
 * next lines are not really needed. Better safe than sorry. */
t_head->some_val = 0;
t_head->prev = NULL;
t_head->next = NULL;
```

Then I can stuff char data into the two char members :

```
strcpy ( t_head->somestring, "birthday" );
strcpy ( t_head->anotherstring, "19981127" );
```

No problem there.

Messing with the conversion of a string to a struct tm seems reasonable within a
function as I have to do it twice perhaps.

Therefore I write this :

```
int timestr_to_tm ( struct tm **date_val, char *yyyymmdd ) {
    /* assume 8 digits received in format YYYYMMDD */
    int j, date_status = -1;
    char yyyy[5]="0000";
    char mm[3]="00";
    char dd[3]="00";

    /* copy over the year digits first */
    for ( j=0; j<4; j++ )
        yyyy[j]=yyyymmdd[j];

    /* month digits */
    mm[0]=yyyymmdd[4];
    mm[1]=yyyymmdd[5];

    /* day digits */
    dd[0]=yyyymmdd[6];
    dd[1]=yyyymmdd[7];

    *(date_val)->tm_year = atoi(yyyy) - 1900;
    *(date_val)->tm_mon = atoi(mm) - 1;
    *(date_val)->tm_mday = atoi(dd);
    *(date_val)->tm_hour = 0;
    *(date_val)->tm_min = 0;
    *(date_val)->tm_sec = 0;
    *(date_val)->tm_isdst = -1;

    return 0;

}
```

So my hope here is that I can pass a pointer to a pointer to the member date_one
within t_node to that function.

```
if ( timestr_to_tm ( &(t_node->date_one), "19981127" ) < 0 ) {
    /* deal with a bad date conversion */
}
```

Well my compiler has a fit here. Claiming :

```
error: argument #1 is incompatible with prototype:
```

Perhaps I should have &t_head->date_one but I think that the pointer dereference
operator "->" takes precedence over the "address of" operator. Perhaps it is bad
policy to even attempt to pass a pointer to a member within a struct?

Even worse, within the function timestr_to_tm() I get :

```
error: left operand of "->" must be pointer to struct/union
```

in those lines where I try to assign values into the struct tm variable.

I tried all this without passing pointers and the process works however upon 
return there is nothing in the struct tm member. So I am wondering, what am 
I missing here ?

Comment: This is a lot to digest. For problems like this, it is much easier on the people helping if you can boil down the issue to a small example that shows/focuses on *only* the problematic code. Many times, this very act of narrowing down the problem makes it apparent to *you* as well, and the problem is solved.

Comment: Also, you have fixed-size strings in your struct. **Do not** use `strcpy`! There is simply no reason to *ever* use `strcpy` in my opinion. Always use `strncpy`, which takes a maximum length paramter. Pass 1 minus the allocated length of your string.

Comment: Another subtle correction to be made: the input string should really be `const char *` so as to indicate that the input won't be modified (and also in order to be able to pass string literals to the function).

Comment: Well, I had pulled this out of something which was severy thousand loc and this is the boiled down version .. sort of. I think I will write a freestanding bit of code that does very very little and see if I can really isolate my issue. I think the issue may be related to casting a pointer to a struct or some similar voodoo.

Comment: to Carbonic Acid ( H2CO3 ) : my intention was that the second parameter was not to be a string const but usually a variable from somewhere else. Valid point however.

Comment: @Beta "At some point you should consider graduating to C++" - I think that is absolutely terrible advice. You make that recommendation having no background on what this application is or where it's going. Also, your use of the word "graduating" implies that C is somehow inferior, or elementary. Quite the opposite, in my opinion. I think C++ programmers should consider graduating to C.

Comment: @H2CO3 In C there is no need to declare a function taking a `const char *` as argument to pass it a string literal because a string literal has type `char []` that decays to `char *`. It is still a good idea, but not for this reason.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: `strcpy` is fine if you know that the target array is big enough to hold the string. `strncpy` is *not* just a "safer" `strcpy`; it will needlessly pad the target with extra null characters or, worse, leave the target without a null terminator (i.e., not a string). To do what you might *expect* `strncpy` to do, you can set the initial byte of the target to `'\0'` and then call `strncat`. [See my rant on the topic](http://the-flat-trantor-society.blogspot.com/2012/03/no-strncpy-is-not-safer-strcpy.html).

Comment: @PascalCuoq (the debate about what the type of string literals continues.) And yes, the principal idea was what I stated too: "[...] so as to indicate that the input won't be modified".

Comment: @Beta Huh, is this related? Not quite. Also Jonathon Reinhart made the point about "graduation", I don't see why C would be worse than C++.

Comment: @KeithThompson on your first point, you may "know" it now, but what happens when someone carelessly makes that literal a little bigger, and bigger... I'm aware of the intricacies of `strncpy`, which is why I mentioned passing 1 minus the allocated length. I forgot to mention the part about ensuring the `'\0'` is there. I appreciate the comment though, and the link, which I am reading now.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: If you like the safety of `strncpy` (which requires careful attention to use it "correctly"), you might consider writing your own replacement that behaves like `target[0] = '\0'; strncat(target, source n)`. I think getting a call to `strncpy` wrong is just as easy as getting a call to `strcpy` wrong. And for a large target array, the `'\0'`-padding is wasteful.

Comment: @KeithThompson Yes, I like the `strncat` semantics. I'm really not sure why they defined/wrote `strncpy` the way they did.

Comment: @H2CO3: It is germane in that this problem is much easier to untangle in C++. And the suggestion that C is superior to C++ is one that I find stunning, especially from someone who then has to get into an extended discussion about *how to copy a char[]*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really want to pass a pointer to a pointer to a struct tm, you can, you just need to create a pointer variable to hold the pointer and pass a pointer to that:

```
struct tm *pointer = &t_node->date_one;
if ( timestr_to_tm ( &pointer, "19981127" ) < 0 ) {
    ...
```

The question is why?  You don't need the extra level of indirection as you're not trying to change the pointer, you just want to fill in the struct tm within the node.  So just use a single pointer:

```
int timestr_to_tm ( struct tm *date_val, char *yyyymmdd ) {
    :
    date_val->tm_year = atoi(yyyy) - 1900;
    :
```

then you can call it with a simple pointer and don't need to create an extra pointer variable:

```
if ( timestr_to_tm ( &t_node->date_one, "19981127" ) < 0 ) {
    ...
```

Comment: If only the internet allowed me to pass a cold beer over to you. Perfect. Flawless.  Yes that makes sense. I was making life more complex and you Sir, nailed the problem on the head in one shot.

Comment: @paullanken (so did I, 20 minutes earlier. I love how you appreciate that I put up with your, hm, *basic* questions and bothered explaining all this to you.)

Comment: I do .. in fact ... I am guessing that all that was needed was a more clear manner of expressing it. I was just in the process of thinking "first that the internet works" and secondly "there are great people out there making it work".  You Sir are one of those people. I am only guessing that Carbonic Acid is in a bottle of Coca Cola .. but that is a guess.

Comment: @H2CO3 Of course, once you pushed the OP past his mental obstacles, the accepted answer goes to someone else :-) It only took "one shot" after your continued explanations.

Answer (score 2):

> I think that the pointer dereference operator `->` takes precedence over the "address of" operator

It does, so does it over the dereference, `*` operator. So this, for example:

```
*(date_val)->tm_mday = atoi(dd);
```

should be

```
(*date_val)->tm_mday = atoi(dd);
```

***But:*** Why would you do this? Why not pass a pointer to the `struct tm`, and use `->` without one more level of indirection?

Comment: The issue is that I am dealing with a large pile of linked list nodes in which are pointers to other structs and then within them there are etc etc etc. A classic example is the kstat kernel stats chain within Solaris servers. In any case I have a node in hand and in scope and within that there is a struct tm member that I need to pull out ( or isolate ) and pass it to a function which will load in time data from some other variable of format YYYYMMDD.  So I am sort of stuck looking at pointer syntax here. What fun.

Comment: @paullanken Isn't then `str_to_tm(&node->struct_tm, "19940628");` a viable option?

Comment: I just did a quick manpage check on that. You had me there for a second. At the moment I have the function prototype as `int timestr_to_tm ( struct tm **date_val, char *yyyymmdd );` and I call this like so : `if ( timestr_to_tm ( &(t_head->date_one), date_yyyymmdd ) < 0 )` however this results in :  line 1528: error: argument #1 is incompatible with prototype:
        prototype: pointer to pointer to struct tm : "sca23_tt.c", line 132
        argument : pointer to struct tm

Comment: @paullanken That's what I'm talking about. `&(t_head->date_one)` is of type `struct tm *`, but your function takes `struct tm **`. Don't insist I'm wrong because I am not. Instead change your function as per I advised you to do so in this answer.

Comment: Why not pass a pointer to the struct tm ?  I thought that was what I was doing here.  Now I have to go back and really think. There is probably a dirt easy way to do this and I'm making it messy.  Not on purpose either.

Comment: @paullanken You do indeed pass a pointer to `struct tm`, but you make your function accept a pointer-to-pointer-to-`struct tm`. You have one level of indirection between the two types.

Comment: oh hold on a sec ... I think I see ... I'm making an error here .. yes. I just need to sort out the function prototype and this should work as is.

Comment: This was a two char bugfix. Essentially get rid of the extra `*` and then the function prototype is as it should be. Damn.  This was a fine example of how I need to really re-read the whole chapter on pointers and passing them etc etc. Then repeat as needed. Daily perhaps.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Thank you! :) (Given back - your example is also useful, and at least it isn't plagiarism.)

Answer (score 1):

Since I'm too lazy to understand the question, I'll just add this unrelated example which hopefully helps to clear things up.  This is very straightforward, if you use the correct syntax and level of indirection.

```
typedef struct _node node_t;
struct _node {
    node_t* next;
    int     a;
};

void fill_in_int(int* pointer_to_int) {
    *pointer_to_int = 42;
}

void populate_all_nodes(node_t* list, int a_value) {
    node_t* node;

    for (node=list; node; node = node->next) {
        fill_in_int( &(node->a) );       // Pass pointer to member a in node
    }
}
```